# SQL: Update table by mapping two columns to each other

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following two tables:

```
        Table A
+-------------------+
|___User___|__Value_|
|    3     |  a     |
|    4     |  b     |
|    5     |  c     |
|____6_____|__d_____|



        Table B
+-------------------+
|___User___|__Value_|
|    1     |        |
|    4     |        |
|    5     |        |
|____9_____|________|
```

My job is to take `user` from Table A (and their correspondings `value`) and then map it to Table B and insert those values in there. So from the above example Table B should look like this after running the script:

```
        Table B
+-------------------+
|___User___|__Value_|
|    1     |        |
|    4     |  b     |
|    5     |  c     |
|____9_____|________|
```

My question is how can I construct an SQL query that will do this for me in an efficient way, if Table A contains 300,000 + entries and Table B contains 70,000 entries?

*NOTES:* In Table A the `User` field is not unique and neither is the `Value` field. However in Table B, both the `User` and `Value` fields are unique and should not appear more than once. Neither are primary keys for either tables.

Comment: So if you have 2 values in a corresponding with 1 user in b which one of those values should be used for update?

Comment: If there is more than one row for the same `user` in Table A, which row's `value` should be copied into B?

Comment: Good question @AlanHadsell - doesn't matter which row gets copied - it can be either the first occurence or the last of anything that's in the 'value' column for Table A

Comment: In that case, the answer below by @scaisEdge is correct

Comment: Is in every User from table A in table B?

Comment: @AlanHadsell how long would you expect a query like that to execute on tables of a size similar to the one I mentioned?

Comment: Depends on hardware, so it's impossible to answer.  It could be improved by putting indexes on the `user` column of both tables.

Comment: The tables are indexed?

Comment: @scaisEdge no they are not

Comment: If you can add an index on User on both of the table the performance can improve.. a lot .. ad you can try changing the lead table ( the table in update) could be different performance..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could be this

```
update table_b as b 
inner join table_a as a on a.User = b.User
set b.value = a.value
```

Answer (score 1):

In real-world situations, it would be more likely that you want a predictable value, such as the greatest `value` for any given `user`.  In that case you would want

```
update table_b as b
inner join (
   select user, max(value) from table_a
   group by user ) as a_max on a.user = b.user
set b.value = a_max.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear about what to do about any values that are already in `b`.  If you use a `left join`, then these will explicitly be set to `NULL`:

```
update table_b b left join
       table_a a
       on a.User = b.User
    set b.value = a.value;
```

If you want to keep the existing values for non-matches, then use `inner join`.

Note that this might be inefficient, but should be ok if an index exists on `a(user)`.

If you had very few users in `a` and lots and lots of duplicates, then you might want to aggregate `a` before doing the join.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. There's about 50k users, and yes lots of duplicates (300K rows in total). There are no indexes currently on either table. Would I be able to add an index to those tables or would that be something i would had to have done when the table was created? 
Also what do you mean by Aggregating Table a?

Comment: The best index for t his table is on `table_a(user, value)`.